# CSS background image not loading / broken

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I can't manage to load a background image. Here is what I've done:

First try:

```
html { 
  background: url(../images/bg1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Issue: Chrome finds the image (=Path is valid) but displays the "broken" icon in the dev tools

Second try:

```
html { 
  background: url(../images/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Issue: Path is valid, chrome dev tools shows the image (= no "broken" icon) but the image is not visible on the actual website. Just a blank background.

Third try:

```
html { 
  background-image: url(../images/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Issue: I changed `background:` to `background-image`. The image doesn't even load now (= does not show up in chrome dev tools).

Note: bg1 and bg2 seem to be valid, I can view them in the standard windows photo viewer app.

I am quite confused, there is no other css file that overwrites the rules, it's just a page with some text on it. Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the absolute path of HTML file and CSS file

Comment: Why does that matter? The path is correct!

Comment: Already tried to add " to it, does not work.

Comment: background-image: url('../images/bg2.jpg')
you have enclosed in quotes... yes

Comment: Does not work, image is now not even loading :(

Comment: what if you remove no-repeat center center fixed from after background-image.

Comment: where do you locate html, css, image file? I mean their relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you say html{...} but you want that the Body display the wallpaper.
Try that here:

```css
           body{
            background: url(../images/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            }
```

---

Now your website should display the image over the all size

Comment: Thank you!  But it doesn't help. The image still loads and still displays a "broken"-icon instead of the image :(

Comment: Ok, can you try following steps:   - try to open your jpg image on your Computer      -move the image in the same Directory in which your index file is stored and say:    (bg2.jpg)      ...

Comment: Mate, trust me - it is NOT a path-problem!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of Quick research here.
There is no shorthand for background-image there is for background. but the first element needs to be the background-color.
the second is the url
the thrid background-repeat
the fourth is the attachment

for your case this will be

```
background: #FFF url('../images/bg1.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
```

Comment: Thank you!  But it doesn't help. The image still loads and still displays a "broken"-icon instead of the image :(

Comment: just tested both solutions with a random image from google both work. You must not be referencing your image correctly

background: #FFF url('http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/wallpapers-for-desktop-background/wallpapers-for-desktop-background-27.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;

Comment: Alright, so it seems to be a different problem. Thank you for your help, I'll answer this post if I find a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my CSS code

```
.body_background {
background-image: url(body_background.gif);
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;
}
```

This is my HTML code and it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PreventQuestionLeak.css">
</head>
<body class="body_background">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some CSS that worked fine on a Mac in Safari.
But was broken in Chrome and Firefox Developer edition.

### Safari Version

[image: Safari Version]

### Correct Rendering:

[image: Correct Rendering]

### Firefox Edition

[image: Firefox Dev Edition]

### Broken Rendering

[image: Firefox Render broken]

### Chrome Version

### [image: Chrome Version]
Chrome Rendering

[image: Chrome Rendering broken]

For me I found the issue was CSS interpreter was broken if the url was placed in the background property.
I took the url out of background and used background-image: url() instead and it worked across all 3 browsers afterwards.

This [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) provided the inspiration.

### Before (broken)

```
card-1 {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, .6),rgba(0,0,0, .5)), url(images/pricing-card-bg.jpeg) center no-repeat /cover;
    box-shadow: 7px 18px 50px #555;
}
```

### After (fixed)

```
card-1 {
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, .6),rgba(0,0,0, .5)), url(images/pricing-card-bg.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 7px 18px 50px #555;
}
```

### Footnote:

I later found [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) on W3Schools:

> ```
> background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin
> bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;
> ```

So for me the correct shorthand should have been:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, .6),rgba(0,0,0, .5)), url(images/pricing-card-bg.jpeg) center  /cover no-repeat;
```

The `no-repeat` and `/cover` were the wrong way around. It's just Safari is more forgiving.